# Component lifecycle hook beforeDestroy gets called on new component creation using v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hello I have a simple vue component for.eg an InputField Component. Now I need to do different operations during life cycle of the component. One of them is to update an object with the state of this component if it's being destroyed. Now I am looping over an array with a v-for to create multiple instances of the same component.

The problem that I face is that when I have created an element with index 0 and now that I create an index of 1, then beforeDestroy is called for the previous element with index zero. This makes the lifecycle method totally useless to work with.

Has anybody faced something similar and have any workaround?
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually quite simple. I was looping over a dynamic component so I had to use keep alive around it like:
`<keep-alive> <component :is="view"></component> </keep-alive>` 
This ensures that it caches the inactive component instances without destroying them.

[VueJS Keep alive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive)